# Setting the line spacing to 1.5 pt in R Markdown

Tags: r-markdown, line-spacing

I am writing my thesis in r markdown and I need a line spacing of 1.5 pt for this. Is there any way to modify the line spacing in markdown? Output will be pdf.

Comment: Your best bet is to set both the font size and line height. The methods to incorporate this type of styling constraint depends on what options you've put in your YAML.